# Contour Integration Line Segment

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\gamma$ be the line segment from $z=i$ to $z=1$. Without evaluating the integral, show that
$$
\left| \int_\gamma \frac{1}{z^4}dz\right| \le 4\sqrt{2}
$$
I know that the integral is at point $z=0$ and under the line segment. That is for $\frac{1}{z-w}, w=0. $Not sure if it is holomorphic or not but if it is then its value is 2$\pi i$ which would seem correct. However, how may I deduce the inequality without evaluation of the integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the next inequality [Estimation Lemma](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma) :
$$
\left| \int_{\gamma} f(z) dz \right| \leq M \cdot Long(\gamma)
$$
where $M=\max_t \{|f(\gamma(t))|\}$. Note for example that in your case $\gamma(t)=(1-t)i+t$ for $t\in [0,1]$, thus $Long(\gamma)=\sqrt{2}$, so basically you have to calculate $M$ and you are done.